# Scrapy neither shows any error nor fetches any data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Tried to parse product name and price from a site using scrapy. However, When i run my scrapy code it neither shows any error nor fetches any data. What I'm doing wrong is beyond my capability to find out. Hope there is someone to take a look into it.

"items.py" includes:

```
import scrapy
class SephoraItem(scrapy.Item):
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Price = scrapy.Field()
```

spider file named "sephorasp.py" contains:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class SephoraspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sephorasp"
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.ae']
    start_urls = ["https://www.sephora.ae/en/stores/"]
    rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="level0 nav-1 active first touch-dd  parent"]')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="level2 nav-1-1-1 active first"]'),
            callback="parse_item")
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info"]')
        for titles in page:
            Product = titles.xpath('.//a[@title]/text()').extract()
            Rate = titles.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
            yield {'Name':Product,'Price':Rate}
```

Here is the Link to the Log:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xktgh7lvj4uhbh/output.log?dl=0"

It works when I play around with BaseSpider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class SephoraspSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "sephorasp"
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.ae']
    start_urls = [
                    "https://www.sephora.ae/en/travel-size/make-up",
                    "https://www.sephora.ae/en/perfume/women-perfume",
                    "https://www.sephora.ae/en/makeup/eye/eyeshadow",
                    "https://www.sephora.ae/en/skincare/moisturizers",
                    "https://www.sephora.ae/en/gifts/palettes"

    ]

    def pro(self, response):
        item_links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"level0")]/@href').extract()
        for a in item_links:
            yield Request(a, callback = self.end)

    def end(self, response):
        item_link = response.xpath('//a[@class="level2"]/@href').extract()
        for b in item_link:
            yield Request(b, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info"]')
        for titles in page:
            Product= titles.xpath('.//a[@title]/text()').extract()
            Rate= titles.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
            yield {'Name':Product,'Price':Rate}
```

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider -s LOG_FILE=output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider &> output.log` commands.

Comment: Thanks sir  Granitosaurus for your response. I already added what you looked for. I could not upload in searchable format, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpaths are heavily flawed.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="level0 nav-1 active first touch-dd  parent"]')),
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="level2 nav-1-1-1 active first"]'),
```

You are matching whole class ranges which can change at any point and the order might be different in scrapy. Just pick one class, it's most likely unique enough:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[contains(@class,"level0")]')),
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[contains(@class,"level2")]')),
```

Comment: Dear sir Granitosaurus, I ran my code using your rectified xpaths but got newer errors in the console which I have uploaded. The image you can see above is the updated one. Thanks.

Comment: Dear sir Granitosaurus, I've caught the log as you suggested but can't upload it. It's huge. Could you tell me how can i ?

Comment: @SMth80 use some sort of pastebin, e.g. http://codepad.org/ to upload your log and share the link.

Comment: Ok sir, gonna do that. Btw, if i write the code using Basespider then it works more or less. Already updated the working one above. I wanted to parse without feeding any url, though.